# Console says my state "entries" is not defined? Can you help me, how to define state in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

Here I create TodoItems component, and I try to store array as a state, but console says that my entries is not defined:

```
var TodoItems = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() {
          return {
            entries: this.props.entries
          };
        },

      removeItem: function(key){
        var itemArray = this.state.entries;
        for (var i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++)
          if (itemArray[i.key] === key) {
              itemArray.splice(i, 1);
              break;
          }
          this.setState({
            entries: entries
          })
      },
```

This is the prop I'm trying to store:

```
</div>
    <TodoItems entries={this.state.items}/>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `entries` in `removeItem`? It isn't defined

Comment: corrected extra code indentation and capitalisation

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a mistake, setting state as `entries` in removeItem function whereby you should be setting it to `itemArray`, also , assign itemArray as `var itemArray = [...this.state.entries];` because in your style of declaration it will refer to the state entries itself and will mutate state directly, which is not advisable, and `getInitialState` is called only on the `first render of TodoItems` so if you are assigning a state with props make sure to do that in the `componentWillReceiveProps` function as well, since it will be called everytime the parent renders and will have the updated props

```
var TodoItems = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() {
          return {
            entries: this.props.entries
          };
        },
        componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
             this.setState({entries: nextProps.entries})
        }
      removeItem: function(key){
        var itemArray = [...this.state.entries];
        for (var i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++)
          if (itemArray[i.key] === key) {
              itemArray.splice(i, 1);
              break;
          }
          this.setState({
            entries: itemArray
          })
      },
```

Comment: Okay now I got another error, but old one seems to be gone, thank you! New error crashes whole localhost, and says "setstate cannot update during an existing state transition". Can you help with this

Comment: Yes, but it depends on how you are using the rest of the code, which isn't mentioned in your question. So I think you can close this and ask a new one